# Do I need a license to create a PDF and send it over e-mail?

Tags: pdf, license

Let's say I am a corporation which sells some product. Before selling product I need some documents signed by my customers.

If I create some PDF and send these PDFs to my customers to signing, do I need a licence to create these PDFs ?

Comment: See : http://superuser.com/questions/360340/do-i-need-a-license-to-create-pdf-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDF files themselves are not licensed - The software that creates them may be.

**Adobe** - you can have reader for free, but writer typically costs money.

**Open Source/Freeware** - you can have Foxit reader for free, PDF creator for free, HTML2PDF (TCPDF) for free... etc.

You do not need a license to create a PDF file, just the same as you don't need a Word license to create DOC files (you can use OpenOffice for instance)

Your customers will need a reader/writer capable of signing PDF files - but what software they use to do this (and the associated licensing costs) are their problem - not yours.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the software you use to create the PDF file. Some are free, others aren't.

The file format itself is open (ISO 32000) and, since 2008 there is no license payment required to create [PDFs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF).

Comment: I will use a PDF creator from HTML which is open-source. My concern is sending them and using it as an offical paper, lets say an agreement document. Is this a problem ?

Comment: Just a hint for signing document on PDF files, when you send the copy for your customer be sure you have locked the editing option, That's happened to me before and put me in trouble

Comment: @CrimsonKing - Check with a lawyer.  "is this a problem" type questions are to broad for Superuser.